# sfdx update fails, Error: EPERM: operation not permitted

Tags: sfdx-error

Went to create a new scratch org, and got a warning:

```
Warning: sfdx-cli update available from 7.102.0 to 7.104.0.
```

The scratch org created without issue, but I figured I may as well update to latest CLI version. I ran sfdx update and get the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\A Person\Projects\BluVector\SalesVector> sfdx update
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI from 7.102.0-dd7aac3 to 7.104.0-8acfa0e... done
sfdx-cli: Updating CLI... done
    Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\A Person\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.102.0-dd7aac3\bin\node.exe'
    Code: EPERM
The batch file cannot be found.
```

Hints?

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same error right now. I added the location to environment variables and its working fine now.

For those who didn't understand anything I said above,
What I did was,

- I went to the location specified in the error.
- Copied the location.(Here, its here => C:\Users\A Person\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.102.0-dd7aac3\bin)
- Search for environment variables in windows search bar
- Select 'Edit the System Environment Variables' and press 'Environment Variables' button under 'Advanced' Tab.
- Select path and click on edit.
- Click New.
- Paste the location. Here, it is =>  C:\Users\A Person\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.102.0-dd7aac3\bin
- Click Ok for all windows and restart your VSCode.

Its Done !

Try this and correct me if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Agreed, yes this fixes the error as late as 7.165.0 (Aug 25, 2022) [stable].

I believe it occurs whenever you execute "sfdx update" from outside this path (a bug they should really fix), but an alternative might be simply to run it from that folder (rather than adding permanently to your path, if this is the only time it's needed, as this can slow down executable/command line performance, since every folder in your path must be searched each time you issue a command, in the order listed in your path).

Also FWIW here is a more complete version of the error, which may be helpful in surfacing this StackExchange post via Google search results, since this thread didn't immediately come up when I entered the complete error message:

> user plugins are
> Error: '
> Code: EPERMEPERM: operation not permitted, unlink
> 'C:\Users[%USERPROFILE%]\AppData\Local\sfdx\client\7.148.3-dsbf0a7b\bin\node.exe
> The batch file cannot be found.

Also, above this message when installing 7.165.0, I got the additional message/warning:

> - NEW: When we publish the sfdx executable of Salesforce CLI to npm, we lock down its dependencies. As a result, users installing sfdx from npm get immutable builds. See Locking dependencies with npm shrinkwrap (https://github.com/forcedotcom/cli/issues/1678) for details.

As per the link above:

> "Starting in version 7.165.0 of sfdx, installing via npm produces the exact dependency tree that was used when we created the release.

> Why are we making this change?
> For installations of sfdx <= 7.164.2, npm installed newer versions of the CLI's dependencies, which sometimes resulted in errors because we hadn't tested those exact combinations. Starting in version 7.165.0, we lock down the CLI dependencies with a shrinkwrap lockfile. As a result, users installing sfdx from npm now get immutable builds."

Curiously, though, after adding to the path and executing "sfdx update" a second time (also from my home/user profile directory), the output at the end instead of the error was simply:

> "user plugins are"

...with nothing after it. I assume that means everything installed correctly, and I have no plugins.

So I think all is well. :-)